# How to get updated location using background service for Network provider in Android?

Tags: android, gps

i was unable to switch provider from GPS to Network in background service.With help Gps provider i get updated location periodically using background service but when GPS is off then how get latitude & longitude of updated location?

Comment: you have to use a GeoIP service.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: how to use GeoIP service in android?

Comment: Actually with help Gps i get updated location ,but when turn off GPS then i was unable to get updated location.My question how to get updated location using network provider in android?

Answer (score 3):

You should use **LocationManager** in **Service**

```
LocationManager locationManager; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);     
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i("location...","...latt"+location.getLatitude()+"longg..."+location.getLongitude());
        String my_latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String my_longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    }
```